# Why am I receiving a 203/EXEC Error for my Wildfly.service?

Tags: wildfly, ubuntu-18.04, status, systemctl, wildfly-26

I've currently been trying to run WildFly 26.1.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 AWS VM.

So far I've created a script in order to install and have it running on both 8080 and 9990 (Administration Console), but I've now come across this error.

`systemd[1]: wildfly.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC`
`systemd[1]: wildfly.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

This is what my wildfly.service looks like

```
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/var/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is what it currently looks like in the file path (systemd) where wildfly.service is located.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 wildfly wildfly 645 May 18 19:08 README
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wildfly wildfly 217 May 18 19:08 launch.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 wildfly wildfly 165 May 18 19:08 wildfly.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wildfly wildfly 419 Jun 15 21:09 wildfly.service
```

To clarify, I had previously managed to run it several times using my script, and now it's suddenly not working (it had also previously given me an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when WildFly was properly running)

All help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I find out my issue.

It was due to the launch.sh that was being copied over from `/opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd` being different to what was I was later copying it into - `/opt/wildfly/bin/`.

The reason why I was making the change in the first place was because I needed to change the change the contents of `launch.sh` in order to run port 9990, but since the two locations had different results I'm guessing the aforementioned error was occurring?

However, now I've come across a different issue in that in order to run my custom webpage on both port 8080 and 9990 I have to remove the `https://` at the beginning of my URL.